# declaring objects in C++ vs java

Tags: java, c++, new-operator

I have been using c++ for a while now and I am learning java,

declaring objects in java is confusing me,

In java we write

```
myclass myobject = new myclass();
myobject.mymethod();
```

Is it same as this code in c++ ?

```
myclass *myobject = new myclass();
myobject->mymethod();
```

i.e is the memory getting allocated on `heap`? If it is on heap why we never free the memory. I believe the new keyword is the same.
If so, how do we allocate memory on stack?

Comment: "how do we allocate memory on stack?" – in Java, you can't (except primitive types).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it same as this code in c++ ?

Yes. It's the same.

> i.e is the memory getting allocated on heap?

Yes it.

> If it is on heap why we never free the memory.

The object is allowed to garbage collector when it is no more reachable. i.e when there are no valid reference to that object or (de-referenced)

> If so, how do we allocate memory on stack?

When the particular thread execution starts, variables related to that thread will be placed on stack and will be remove immediately once the job of that thread finished. Every thread has it's own stack.

Comment: new keyword returns a pointer to the allocated memory in the heap right? but there are no pointers in java...

Comment: But references are a different thing in c++. I still don't understand what the new keyword is doing and why the call to new is needed if always the memory is allocated in heap.

Answer (score 1):

As you thought, the `new` operator allocates a new object on the heap. Memory in Java is not freed explicitly - once an object has no more access roots, it is eligible for being freed. Periodically, a garbage collection thread will free this memory.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst it is not inaccurate to say that this `C++` code is equivalent:

```
myclass* myobject = new myclass();
myobject->mymethod();
```

It is also not exactly the same.

Java has a *Garbage Collector* and so, as you note, you do not have to free the object in `Java`.

So a closer approximation to the original `Java` might be this:

```
std::shared_ptr<myclass> myobject = std::make_shared<myclass>();
myobject->mymethod();
```

Now you do not have to deallocate `myobject` it gets *garbage collected* when there are no longer any references to it.

However it would be a mistake in `C++` to use [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) for every heap-allocated object because it really drags down the performance.

As a rule it is better to manage the *heap allocated object* in one place using a [std::unique_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). If it is impossible to know which component will be the last to de-reference the object, a [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) should be used in each place.

However when calling *down* to functions from the component that holds the smart pointer you should pass the *raw pointer* or a *reference*:

```
std::shared_ptr<myclass> myobject = std::make_shared<myclass>();
myobject->mymethod();

ptr_needing_func(myobject.get()); // pass raw pointer using get()

ref_needing_func(*mtobject.get()); // pass reference using *get()
```

This way you don't lose any efficiency while still maintaining the safety and convenience of *garbage collecting* smart pointers.

**See:** [CppCoreGuidlines: R.23](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#r32-take-smart-pointers-as-parameters-only-to-explicitly-express-lifetime-semantics)

Answer (score 0):

After reading other answers to this question and some other articles, I understood that,

Both the c++ and java code are doing the very similar thing except the syntax is different and java is using references instead of pointers(Java doesn't have pointer).

Here,

`myclass myobject;` is a **declaration** of myobject,

Declarations simply notify the compiler that we will be using myobject to refer to a variable whose type is myclass. It is not allocating the memory.

`new myclass();`  is **instantiating** the object (allocating the memory in the heap) and returning the reference to it.
 It is also **initializing** the object by calling the constructor myclass().

Clarification of a very basic doubt,

`int i;` ==> Declaring the object *and allocating memory* for it in stack.

`myclass myobject;`==> Only declaring the reference variable for the object(It also takes 4 bytes or 8 bytes depending on system). It does not allocate actual memory where the instance variables will be stored.

In other words, memory is allocated while declaring for the primitive data types but not for the non-primitive data type. For non-primitive data types we need to allocate them using new keyword.

> Why we never free the memory?

Java has garbage collector that does it for us automatically.

> How do we allocate memory for objects in stack?

We can't. Only primitive data types can be stored in stack.