# JVM allocates memory at declaration for primitive types, but not for non-primitive types?

Tags: java

I am from a C/C++ background and very new to java, I am having difficulty in understanding variable declaration and memory allocation in java.

when we write,

```
myclass myobject;
```

we declare that myobject is a variable of type myclass. We are not allocating memory to it.

```
int a;
```

It declares the variable a and also allocates memory equal to size of int in stack.

Is it the case? Does the compiler allocate memory for the primitive data types but not for the non-primitive data types?

I've raised a similar doubt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807356/declaring-objects-in-c-vs-java).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Compiler does't allocate memory. Its JVM who allocate memory

For primitive data type memory is allocated at time of declaration of those variable and memory is taken in that function local stack. 
`int x;`

> memory allocated in stack 4 byte

When we use new operator then memory is allocated to heap which is the size of class's data member. 
`MyClass object;`

> This is reference variable also takes size of 4 byte

`object = new MyClass();`

> new operator allocate memory in heap and size is sum of all individual
>   data member's size of that class.

Comment: Primitive data types can be members and can therefore live on the heap. The size of a reference isn't specified. Don't use quote formatting for text that isn't quoted.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it the case? Does the compiler allocate memory for the primitive data types but not for the non-primitive data types?

First point to note is Compiler won't allocate any memory. JVM do that.

Coming to actual question, Yes. For primitives weather you initialize it or not later, once you declare, the memory allocates.

Here is the amount of data for primitives

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

For objects, at the time of initialization, the memory allocates. The size of memory really depends on the Class data.

Comment: Are you sure that unitialized variables allocate memory when they are declared? As for the bytecode, there is nothing that says "the variable is declared at this point" - the variable only pops into existence at the first `*STORE` instruction that stores the top value on the stack into a local variable slot. Every method in Java bytecode has a `MAXLOCALS` attribute for a reason - to tell the JVM how much memory to allocate for the stack frame.

Comment: @Clashsoft As far as I know, for fields the memory allocates on Heap and local variables pops to stack.

Comment: @Clashsoft Of course they do. Where do you think the default values are stored?

Answer (score 0):

In java the declaration of the variable doesn't mean allocate memory space but means this variable can hold a reference of an object with the same type of its class(or subclass) later.

`MyClass myObject;`   // myObject has null value (declaration only)

The memory space is allocating when you write :

`MyClass myObject = new MyClass();` // when we use the new operator  (the allocating occurs )

Now myObject has the reference which points to the resulted object from new MyClass() , and the size of this object depends on the data fields in its class declaration.

**Conclusion**

The statement

`int a;` // allocate fixed size because int size is known and can't change it

`MyClass myObject;` // has null value

`myObject = new MyClass();` // now has a reference of this object

I wish this help you :) .

Comment: All variables occupy memory. Reference variables occupy enough memory for the reference, and the objects they can point to occupy more memory.

Comment: "MyClass myObject; // has null value" This is only true for fields! Local variables don't get default values.

Answer (score 0):

In Java,
when we declare a variable of a class type, only a reference is created (memory is not allocated for the object). To allocate memory to an object, we must use new() and all objects are dynamically allocated on Heap.

in C++ where objects can be allocated memory either on Stack or on Heap. when we allocate the object using new(), the object is allocated on Heap.

[Understanding Memory Management](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/garbage_collect.html)