# Does stating but not initializing an object allocate memory?

Tags: java, optimization

To further explain my question. Does simply writing `String foo;` allocate memory. Or is memory only set aside when the variable is given value for the first time? Thanks.

Comment: Typically it will allocated some memory somewhere, either on the heap or the stack.  However if you *never* use a variable a compiler will typically eliminate it, using no memory at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [variable declaration and memory allocation in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32810120/variable-declaration-and-memory-allocation-in-java)

Comment: Those are some pretty terrible answers in that question you quoted.  I'm pretty sure the accepted answer is flat out wrong.

Comment: @markspace How is it terrible? All of them state declaring a variable consumes memory. Not to mention, you don't mark posts duplicate because the duplicate has better answers - you mark duplicate because the question has been asked before..

Comment: Do they? I thought they said declaring a variable takes no memory.  I'll check again.

Comment: @markspace "*memory is allocated at time of declaration*" - "*Coming to actual question, Yes. ... weather you initialize it or not later, once you declare, the memory allocates.*" If you feel they can be improved (due to focus on primitive types), anyone can edit them. If you're rep hounding, could write your own answer. Don't encourage duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have not declared an object here. You have declared a *reference variable*. The variable occupies memory, and so does the object it refers to after you initialize it.

Comment: Actually ... he has declared a variable (which may *contain* a reference).

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer this differently because I think the linked (duplicate) answers are wrong.

Memory **IS** allocated when you just declare a reference.

```
public MyClass {
   public String s;
}
```

That reference `s` needs 8 byes on the heap (typically, most JVMs).  The memory has to be there.

Now when you assign it, more memory gets allocated.

```
public static void main( String args... ) {
   MyClass c = new MyClass();
   c.s = new String("Hello Memory");
}
```

The string `"Hello Memory"` takes memory too, but the reference `s` still takes up 8 byes on the heap and is part of the memory that gets allocated when `MyClass` gets created.  In addition, all Java objects have about 8 bytes of additional overhead on the heap (all Java objects have a monitor associated with them, so that takes overhead).

And in the method `main`, `c` takes 8 bytes as well (on the stack), *in addition* to the memory that that `new` needs to allocate on the heap.  I really think you need to account for this sort of allocation if you want to understand how memory works.

---

I'm probably going to flub this up, because memory allocation gets tricky, but here's how this program allocates memory, starting with `main`.

First `c` gets allocated when `main` is invoked: 8 bytes.

Then `new MyClass()` allocates 16 bytes (the size of `s` + 8 bytes overhead) on the heap.

Next, (are you ready for this?) `new String("Hello Memory");` allocates 48 bytes on the heap.  Why?  Java strings are declared like this:

```
public final String {
   private final char[] string;
   private int hashcode;
}
```

So 8 bytes overhead for the string object, plus 12 bytes overhead for the array (arrays are objects and also need the length of the array, so normal 8 byte overhead + 4 bytes for the length).  The `hashcode` field takes another 4 bytes, and the string data "Hello Memory" takes 24 bytes (12 `chars` at 2 bytes each).  If I've done that right it adds up to 48 bytes.  C programmers are either laughing or crying.

Comment: You're right in principle, but many details are wrong. +++ "when you assign it, more memory gets allocated" - taken literally, it's wrong. It's never the assignment, it's the `new` operator. +++ The string `"Hello Memory"` gets allocated at the class loading time as it's a compile time constant. As you wrote, it cost a `char[]` plus the `String` object. +++ Doing `new String("Hello Memory");` *reuses* the array and allocates *another* `String` object. +++ Using `new String(someString)` is pretty always a non-sense. I'd suggest to comment it with "no need for this" or alike.

Comment: Mostly you are right, though I think you are picking at nits.  The example program I have is just an example to talk about how memory gets used.  I guess they might be important in some cases but my goal was just to talk about the difference between memory taken by primitives and references, and memory allocated on the heap by `new`.  One nit of my own: *"Doing new String("Hello Memory"); reuses the array"* Nope.  As of Java 7u6, the char array is no longer reused. http://java-performance.info/changes-to-string-java-1-7-0_06/

Comment: Agreed, it's sort of nitpicking, but think about someone accepting your answer and users reading it and believing it's exact. You may be imprecise when you make it clear. +++ The array does NOT get copied. You're confusing the useless constructor with `substring`. I'm sure as I'm just looking at the source (Java 8).

Answer (score 0):

The memory isn't allocated until you create the string. Simply defining the string is not enough. If you create a string object using string literal, that object is stored in the string constant pool and whenever you create a string object using new keyword, such object is stored in the heap memory.

For example, when you create string objects like below, they will be stored in the String Constant Pool.

```
String s = "abc";
```

And when you create string objects using new keyword like below, they will be stored in the heap memory.

```
String s5 = new String("abc");
```

Comment: I think this is wrong.  Memory **is** allocated when you just declare a reference.  `String s;` takes 8 bytes (typically) when it's a member field or as a local variable or parameter.

Comment: The eight (or four) bytes are for the pointer. @markspace makes the important point that there's memory for the value, and memory for the pointer also.

Comment: @markspace Actually, this is wrong, too. Stack gets allocated when the method gets entered.

Comment: I thought that was kind of obvious, but yes.  If you declare a local variable or a method parameter, that memory is not actually used until the method invocation.  I think even then the details differ  Some code allocates the full stack space when at the call site when the parameters are assigned.  Some do actually use two memory allocations: one at the call site just for the method parameters and then a second inside the method at the very beginning to allocate local variables.  I'm sure other schemes have been tried too, these are just common ones I'm aware of.

Comment: @markspace It isn't a question of 'some code' and others. Java bytecode is defined in the Java Virtual Machine Specification. It behaves one way or the other, and it isn't difficult to look up which it is.

Comment: @MarquisofLorne Once the JIT optimizer gets ahold of it, it can do almost anything at all.  The byte codes themselves are rarely (if ever) executed, nearly all Java code is fully compiled to machine codes before being run.  "Looking up" the byte codes will probably give the wrong information.