# Memory Allocation for Primitives vs References

Tags: java, variables, memory-management

I've read on other answers that memory is allocated for Reference variables *only* after they're initialized, contrary to primitives where memory is allocated right when declared, even if they're not initialized!

Example :

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name;            // no memory allocation
        String name2 = null;    // memory allocated
        int num;                // memory allocated
    }
}
```

To what extent is this true ?

Comment: What answers did you read to arrive at these conclusions?

Comment: @pvg https://stackoverflow.com/a/32810151/3356446

Comment: That answers is a bit confused and doesn't make a distinction between stack and heap usage. Both primitives and references take up some amount of memory and you can think of that as happening at the time of declaration - it really doesn't matter whether the thing is a reference or a primitive. If you init the reference to null, no heap allocation happens, if you initialize it with a newly instantiated object, the object itself is allocated on the heap and the reference now points to the object. The amount of memory the reference itself takes, though, does not change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are local variables and are therefore allocated on the stack. Even the reference is just a 4 byte pointer on the stack to an area in Heap (or metaspace).

Since they are allocated on the stack, memory is allocated for all local variables simultaneously when the function is called. There is no special treatment of references or primitives here.

As for when their values are initialized, the short answer is the compiler likely won't initialize them before it has to, but it is free to reorder statements as it sees fit.

We can verify this by looking at the bytecode generated by the compiler with 'javac Testing.java && javap -c Testing'

```
public class Testing {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n;
        String name = "name";
        n = 1;
        System.out.println(name + n);
    }
}

 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: ldc           #2    // load constant "name"
       2: astore_2            // initialize name to "name"
       3: iconst_1            // load constant 1
       4: istore_1            // initialize n to 1
/** do println stuff */
```

Note there is no instruction corresponding to the declaration of int n even though it's the first statement.

Comment: The astore_2 is not initialize something,just load top element from operant stack into local variable table.The initializing instance by instruction new and invokespecial method that compiler define in class.

Comment: @dabaicai Initialization != instantiation. Loading a variable from the operand stack into the local variable table is the definition of initialization of local variables. Initializing variables may or may not require instantiating an object. name is a reference to a string -- it is initialized when we write a value of a memory address to it.

Comment: Sorry,i think you mean instantiation ago.

Answer (score 0):

For primitive data type is it for sure allocating the fix amount of memory
int the [link](http://cs.fit.edu/%7Eryan/java/language/java-data.html) you can read more
and for reference it just allocate 32 bits which can save the address of the object example

> String name;

just 32 bits are allocated to save the address of the string object
later on when object is instantiated jvm allocates memory for object and save the address in the reference variable